# libspotify API: is there any way to retrieve audio sample rate or bit rate without using "music_delivery" callback?

Tags: spotify

Since the sample rate of different tracks may be different, is there any way to get the sample rate without using **music_delivery** callback? i.e. get the sample rate before playing the track?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there isn't.